# Generate all possible combinations of choices from mutually exclusive options

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an optimisation problem that requires me to test all potential combinations of choices of potential portfolios, that I also need to be able to quickly adapt to exclude certain choices.

This must be done in Excel.

The rules for my sanitised example below:

- I can chose to buy fruit from any of 3 grocers
- The grocers may have different amount of aisles, and different combinations of fruit to select from
- I can only pick one selection of fruit (or no selection at all) from all the grocers

*Combinations*

1. My first combintaon is no fruit from any grocer
2. In the next I pick *apples* from *Aisle 3* from *Grocer3*
3. then *apples* from *Aisle 2* from *Grocer3*
4. then *apples* from *Aisle 1* from *Grocer3*
5. then I pick *apples* from *Aisle 2* from *Grocer2* and nothing from Grocer 3 (ie same  choice from *Grocer 3* as combination 1 etc)
6. thenI pick *apples* from *Aisle 2* from *Grocer2*, and  *apples* from *Aisle 3* from *Grocer3* (ie same  choice from *Grocer 3* as combination 2)
   And so on

All up this will give me `7*4*4 = 112` possible combinations consisting of

- 7 choices for *Grocer 1* (6 selection choices + 1 do nothing)
- 4 choices for *Grocer 2* (3 selection choices + 1 do nothing)
- 4 choices for *Grocer 3* (3 selection choices + 1 do nothing)

**1. Unconstrained Problem**
[image: Unconstrained]

My actual problem is far more complicated but the basic structure holds true.

What I would like to do is have an [excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula) or [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) approach to populate all the available choices for:

1. The unconstrained problem.
2. A constrained problem (for example where I turn off *Aisle 2* giving me 45 valid combinations)

**2. Constrained Problem**
[image: Unconstrained]

**What I have tried**

I did solve an intial problem where the number of grocer options was the same with a `MOD\INT` approach. This was simple with a single formula as the patterns were repeatable.

If there is a smart formula solution then that would be preferred, but I'm open to code (and this is the route I am now trying)

[image]

Comment: + 1 For a nice + Clear + precise question :)

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong... You want to populate Cells `G3:G5` based on `D3:D5` + Row 12?

Comment: I want to populate C15 to Nx where (x-15) is the number of valid combinations

Comment: Oh ok.. `If there is a smart formula solution then that would be preferred, but I'm open to code (and this is the route I am now trying)` I can think of a VBA solution for this :p Can you upload a demo file with which I can play with?

Comment: @SiddharthRout uploaded to [here](https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=5D1B99F93ACE3CA1&id=5D1B99F93ACE3CA1%21122)

Comment: Thanks having a look at it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this Experts-Exchange PAQ http://rdsrc.us/qdl6tl I worked on a very similar problem to enumerate every combination of five different categories of things. The number of things in each category varied. The enumeration had to consider the possibility of no selection in a category as well as any one selection drawn from that category.

I approached the problem as writing a five digit number, where the number of possible digits at each position in the number was a variable.

```
Sub CombinatrixPlus()
'Forms all the combinations of at least two subattributes taken from a selection. _
    No more than one subattribute may be taken from any row.
'Uses variable base counting method

Dim i As Long, ii As Long, j As Long, k As Long, lenSep As Long, _
    m As Long, mCol As Long, mSheet As Long, mRow As Long, _
    N As Long, nBlock As Long, nMax As Long, nWide As Long
Dim v As Variant, vInputs As Variant, vResults As Variant
Dim rg As Range, rgDest As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim s As String, sep As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
sep = ", "      'Separator substring between each subattribute in results
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")   'Put first batch of results in this worksheet
Set rgDest = ws.[A2]      'Put results starting in this cell
mSheet = rgDest.Worksheet.Index
mCol = rgDest.Column
lenSep = Len(sep)
Set rg = Selection      'Cells containing the subattributes
nBlock = 16384          'Maximum number of values in results array

'Clear the previous results
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For i = Worksheets.Count To ws.Index Step -1
    Worksheets(i).Cells.Clear                   'Clear the cells
    If i > ws.Index Then Worksheets(i).Delete   'Delete the sheet
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

N = rg.Rows.Count
nWide = N       'If results lists subattributes in separate cells
'nWide = 1      'If results lists subattributes as a single string with separators
ReDim v(N, 1 To 2)
vInputs = rg.Value
v(0, 2) = 1
For i = 1 To N
    v(i, 1) = Application.CountA(rg.Rows(i))
    v(i, 2) = (v(i, 1) + 1) * v(i - 1, 2)
Next
nMax = v(N, 2) - 1


ReDim vResults(1 To nBlock, 1 To nWide)
For i = 1 To nMax
    s = ""
    m = 0
    ii = ii + 1
    For j = 1 To N
        k = (i Mod v(j, 2)) \ v(j - 1, 2)
        If k <> 0 Then
            m = m + 1
            If nWide > 1 Then vResults(ii, j) = vInputs(j, k)
            s = s & sep & vInputs(j, k)
        End If
    Next
    s = Mid$(s, lenSep + 1)
    If nWide = 1 Then vResults(ii, 1) = s  'Results in a concatentated string
    If m < 2 Then ii = ii - 1

    If ii = nBlock Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Now posting combination " & i & " of " & nMax
        mRow = rgDest.Worksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, mCol).End(xlUp).Row
        If rgDest.Worksheet.Cells(mRow, mCol) <> "" Then mRow = mRow + 1
        If mRow < rgDest.Row Then mRow = rgDest.Row
        If (Rows.Count - mRow) >= nBlock Then
            rgDest.Worksheet.Cells(mRow, mCol).Resize(nBlock, nWide).Value = vResults
        Else
            mSheet = mSheet + 1
            If Worksheets.Count < mSheet Then Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(mSheet - 1)
            With ActiveSheet
                Set rgDest = .Range(rgDest.Address)
                For j = 1 To N
                    .Columns(j).ColumnWidth = ws.Columns(j).ColumnWidth
                Next
                mRow = rgDest.Row
                .Cells(mRow, mCol).Resize(nBlock, nWide).Value = vResults
            End With
        End If
        ii = 0
        ReDim vResults(1 To nBlock, 1 To nWide)
    End If
Next

If ii > 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Now posting combination " & i & " of " & nMax
        mRow = rgDest.Worksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, mCol).End(xlUp).Row
        If rgDest.Worksheet.Cells(mRow, mCol) <> "" Then mRow = mRow + 1
        If mRow < rgDest.Row Then mRow = rgDest.Row
        If (Rows.Count - mRow) >= nBlock Then
            rgDest.Worksheet.Cells(mRow, mCol).Resize(nBlock, nWide).Value = vResults
        Else
            mSheet = mSheet + 1
            If Worksheets.Count < mSheet Then Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(mSheet - 1)
            With ActiveSheet
                Set rgDest = .Range(rgDest.Address)
                For j = 1 To N
                    .Columns(i).ColumnWidth = ws.Columns(j).ColumnWidth
                Next
                mRow = rgDest.Row
                .Cells(mRow, mCol).Resize(nBlock, nWide).Value = vResults
            End With
        End If
    i = rgDest.Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count   'Reset the scrollbar
End If
Application.StatusBar = False   'Clear the status bar
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Brad, I will look to run through this tomorrow - much appreciated.

Comment: +1 This is 99.9% there. It gives me 99 of the 112 combinatons of my trial, missing only a) no selections (1) b) single selections (11).

Comment: For a formula only solution, the worksheet layout is inconvenient. So too is the desire to exclude certain possible values.

Comment: =IF(D11="",INDEX(D$3:D$8,1),IF(MATCH(D11,D$3:D$8,0)=COUNTA(D$3:D$8),"",INDEX(D$3:D$8,MATCH(D11,D$3:D$8,0)+1)))    formula for right-most position

Comment: =IF(COUNTIF(D12:$D12,"?*")>0,C11,IF(C11="",INDEX(C$3:C$8,1),IF(MATCH(C11,C$3:C$8,0)=COUNTA(C$3:C$8),"",INDEX(C$3:C$8,MATCH(C11,C$3:C$8,0)+1))))     formula for other positions

Comment: The above formulas are using three columns of possible values in cells B3:D8. This range includes some blank cells at the bottom of each column. The number of blank cells may vary with column. The formulas restart the list once all combinations are satisfied.

Comment: Test for all combinations listed =IF($A12>=(COUNTA($B$3:$B$8)+1)*(COUNTA($C$3:$C$8)+1)*(COUNTA($D$3:$D$8)+1),"",previously posted formulas)